# How can I add 1 day to a gg.mm.aaaa date

Tags: php, sql, date

A form is retriving data from a MySQL database.

```
$query = $link->query("SELECT Date_ggmmaaaa AS Date 
                       FROM table
                       WHERE Date_aaaammgg BETWEEN CURDATE() + 0 - INTERVAL 1 MONTH + 0 AND CURDATE() + 0");

while($result = $query->fetch_object) {     
    $date.= "<string>".$result->date."</string>";
```

}

Now when I echo `$date`, which is ALWAYS `gg.mm.aaaa` I'd like to add 1 day.

For example if I have:

```
09.02.2013 -> I want to echo 10.02.2013

10.02.2013 -> I want to echo 11.02.2013
```

How can I reach that?

EDIT:

WORKING WELL SOLUTION

```
$query = $link->query("SELECT date_ggmmaaaa AS date, test FROM table WHERE date_aaaammgg BETWEEN CURDATE() + 0 - INTERVAL 1 MONTH + 0 AND CURDATE() + 0 AND div1 = 0 AND div4 <> 0");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $result['date']);
        $dt->modify('+1 day');
        $result['date'] = $dt->format('d.m.Y');
        $date .= "<string>".$result['date']."</string>";
        $test .= "<number>".$result['test']."</number>";
}
```

Comment: ups :P I cutted some other stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $result->date);
$dt->modify('+1 day');
$result->date = $dt->format('d.m.Y');
```

Comment: works perfeclty, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result->date=$result->date+86400;  //<-- Try that
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use this:

```
echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime("+1 day",strtotime('10-02-2013')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use dots you may have to explode first:

```
$tmp = explode(".",$result->date);
echo date("d.m.Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $tmp[1], $tmp[0]+1, $tmp[2]));
```